# How to "scramble" (Not Randomly) all of the pixels in a picture?

Tags: c#, vb.net, jpeg, pixel

What would be the best way to essentially scramble all of the pixels in a picture, thereby distorting it so you can no longer recognize what it is depicting, however not randomly, so if you wanted to, you could unscramble the pixels and obtain the original picture? And I don't necessarily want the code to scramble every picture the same way, if that's at all possible. I have no preference on exactly what language it would be, as long as it's not too ridiculous and it works.

I have searched far and wide and cannot find anything on actually moving the pixels around in a controlled manner... just changing the Hex values and whatnot...

Any Help?

Comment: Use encryption/decryption, treating the image as a `byte[]`.

Comment: By scramble, do you mean shuffle pixels' order? If you shuffle randomly but remember the random seed, you should be able to "unshuffle" again.

Comment: Remember you can't use JPEG or any other lossy format for this. Once saved, some pixels will be changed and unscrambling will either produce a recognizable wreck of the original image or total random noise. PNG should be the best bet

Comment: I just attempted a pure "moving pixels around", and the result is disappointing. On screenshots and high resolution photograph, you can guess the type of the image (screen capture, picture of green stuff, etc). Follow @Enigmativity suggestion for using encryption.

Comment: What would be interesting would be to take the original picture as in [Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) so that not only is the original distorted, it is distorted into something that does not look distorted.

Comment: If you don't want to be able to guess the type of image, you probably want to follow @Enigmativity's suggestion. Shuffling pixels on a photo of a green field will still leave you with a largely green image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, don't mean to dig up a dead thread, but I think I might have an answer for what you're looking for.

I just made my first Android app, and it does exactly this. If you want to check it out [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.danbuntu.pixelscrambler&hl=en).

My idea was to move each pixel to a different (random as possible) spot using a password, but still be able to undo each move to restore the same image with the password. If you have a 1000 x 1000 image and you move each pixel independently, that's 1,000,000 operations, which would probably take a long time, so instead the program moves each row and column independently from each other, which takes it down to about 2000 operations.

But if you "rearrange" each row and each column, you get a weird looking pattern which isn't completely random, so the next step in the process is to slant the image and scramble the rows and columns again.

With this method you can also group up the rows and columns to get a "block" scramble

And everything is reversible if you do it backwards to get you the original, but a couple of things to note: You have to use a non-lossy image format or else it messes everything up (PNG, BMP, etc.), and if you modify the "scrambled" image (resize, rotate, crop, skew) even by 1 row / column, you can't unscramble it at all

[image: Here's the complete process]

Getting the "key" from the password was the hard part, I can post some of the code if you would like, it's in Java though.

Answer (score 1):

So your idea is to scramble the picture by moving pixels in the picture, you want more variants and on top of that you want it to descramble.
Well, that is pretty challenging,

**Unless you cheat: DETERMINISTIC CHAOS!**

Deterministic chaos is built on the notion, that simple reversible operations could describe after many runs chaos.

You can define set of reversible operations.

For example,

```
swap_horizontal_lines(h_line_a, h_line_b);
swap_vertical_lines(v_line_a, v_line_c);
another could be rotate_pixel_RGB(x,y);
```

RGB => GBR => BRG => RGB
So by applying the operation three times, you get back original value.

And so on...
You can for example access the picture in byte form, and swap its bytes.

So if you would apply these operations in some order only you know, you can scramble the picture that even its mother CMOS sensor would not recognise that it is its children:).
And by applying the order backwards, you can get the picture back.
Just be careful on rgb rotations, it needs 3 runs to reverse.

scrambling_runs  => descramlbing_runs

```
0 => 0 or 3,
1 => 2
2 => 1
3 => 0 or 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to "move" the pixels. Each pixel is represented by hex values, so if you "move" pixel 1 to a different location, then the Hex value of location 1 will change to the value of the pixel you replace it with. So effectively, all you did was change the Hex value of position 1. You didn't really "move" anything. So why not, just create an algorithm to change the hex values in a predetermined way, that you can decipher.

Answer (score 0):

An approach in VB:

```
Public Sub swap(ByVal b As Drawing.Bitmap, ByVal i As Integer, ByVal j As Integer)  'Scramble5
        Dim c1 As Drawing.Color = b.GetPixel(i Mod b.Width, i \ b.Width)
        Dim c2 As Drawing.Color = b.GetPixel(j Mod b.Width, j \ b.Width)
        b.SetPixel(i Mod b.Width, i \ b.Width, c2)
        b.SetPixel(j Mod b.Width, j \ b.Width, c1)
    End Sub

    Public Function Scramble5(a As String) As Bitmap    'a filename
        Dim f As New IO.FileStream(a, IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim b As New Drawing.Bitmap(f)
        f.Close()
        Dim sz As Integer = b.Width * b.Height - 1
        Dim w(sz) As Boolean
        Dim r As New Random(666)
        Dim u As Integer, j As Integer = 0
        Do While j < sz
            Do
                u = r.Next(0, sz)
            Loop While w(u)
            ' swap
            swap(b, j, u)
            w(j) = True
            w(u) = True
            Do
                j += 1
            Loop While j < sz AndAlso w(j)
        Loop
        'b.Save(IO.Path.ChangeExtension(a, "png"), Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        Console.WriteLine("Done!")
        Return b
    End Function
```

Calling for encode and decode with seed pseudor 666:

```
'encode
PictureBox2.Image = Scramble5(Application.StartupPath & "\imagecopy.bmp")
'decode
PictureBox3.Image = Scramble5(Application.StartupPath & "\imagecopy.bmp")
```